# Copy paste csv to xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I will place the vba code in suni.xlsm
my sheet name can be anything
my all file are in same place
Open the file
Completely Copy the first sheet data of anu.csv(here sheet name can be anything) and paste it to sheet1 of anu1.xlsx(here sheet name can be anything)
close and save the workbook
this all i have to do by vba

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend being more specific in your title. It's hard to understand what the question is.

Comment: CSV file do not have a first sheet. they are all one file. I think you mean to have a macro in suni.xlsm that will open anu.csv and copy the file into sheet2 of anu1.xlsx close and save anu1.xlsx.    If so, you will have to post some code that you use to try and do this.  This site is for fixing code, not for writing code.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This website it not a slave labor place, but rather a place where people contribute and help each other. It's hard to understand your post, but one thing is certain - you told us what you would like, and now please provide the code that you tried to use to get that result.

Comment: Sub Mysub
 
   dim wbk1 as workbook
   dim wbk2 as workbook
   dim wsh1 as worksheet
   dim wsh2 as worksheet
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
   Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\anu.csv")
   Set wsh1 = wbk1.Worksheets(1)
 
   Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\anu1.xlsx")
   Set wsh2 = wbk2.Worksheets(1)
 
 
   
 
end if
 
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   wbk1.Close SaveChanges:=True
   wbk2.Close SaveChanges:=True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
end sub

Comment: I know only this much i dont have any idea above this